# Can not project image on the exit screen

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

The problem is: When I close main program I have a little window with some image (Exit screen) and this image is not visible, only frame. I have also another image when I launch program and this image is visible on the screen but the second (when close) isn't. When I compile this class in Eclipse everything works OK but when I run the MAIN program it doesn't. Both are generated from the same class but the difference is in constructor's arguments. Both PNG files are in the folder where JAR file of this project and WorkSpace are. Please help.

SplashScreen code:

```
package Models;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

import MainProject.ExpertSystem;




public class SplashScreen extends JWindow {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int duration;
    private ExpertSystem context;
    private String graphicPath;
    private boolean exit = false;
    int width,height;
    private boolean showContext;

    public SplashScreen(int d, ExpertSystem context,String graphicPath,boolean exit,int width, int height,boolean showContext) {
    duration = d;
    this.graphicPath = graphicPath;
    this.context = context;
    this.exit = exit;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.showContext = showContext;
    showSplashAndExit();
  }
    public SplashScreen(int d)
    {
        duration = d;
    }

  // A simple little method to show a title screen in the center
  // of the screen for the amount of time given in the constructor
  public void showSplash() {

    JPanel content = (JPanel)getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.white);

    // Set the window's bounds, centering the window

    Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (screen.width-width)/2;
    int y = (screen.height-height)/2;
    setBounds(x,y,width,height);

    // Build the splash screen
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(graphicPath));
    JLabel copyrt = new JLabel("Copyright 2013, Dariusz Kruk", JLabel.CENTER);
    copyrt.setFont(new Font("Sans-Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
    content.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.add(copyrt, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //Color oraRed = new Color(156, 20, 20,  255);
   // content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(oraRed, 0));

    // Display it
    setVisible(true);

    // Wait a little while, maybe while loading resources
    try 
    { 
        Thread.sleep(duration); 
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    setVisible(false);
  }

  public void showSplashAndExit() {

      showSplash();
      if(showContext == true)
      {
          context.setVisible(true);
      }
      dispose();
      //System.exit(0);

    if(exit == true)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Throw a nice little title page up on the screen first
   SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen(5000);
    // Normally, we'd call splash.showSplash() and get on with the program.
    // But, since this is only a test...
    splash.showSplashAndExit();
  }
}
```

Launching welcome screen:

```
public ExpertSystem()
    {

        introduction = new SplashScreen(5000,this,"Multimedia/AIWelcome.png",false,478,150,true);
          ..........
          ..........
         }
```

Launching exit screen:

```
else if(input == mWyjscie)
        {

            int odpo=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Czy na pewno wyjsc?","Pytanie",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if(odpo==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                this.setVisible(false);
                exit = new SplashScreen(5000,this,"Multimedia/e.jpg",true,613,173,false);

            }
            else if(odpo==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
            {           
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wait, so you _are_ seeing the image when you first load? Also, is the slash screen for open an close, the same object

Comment: Yes. I see first SplashScreen and only frame of the second. There are two object of SplashScreen class

Comment: So there is no program in between? You're just trying to test out your splash screen?

Comment: It's a part of code I pasted here because it is really long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a problem with you calling `Thread.sleep()`, which blocks the EDT. Maybe you should use a Swing Timer, or even `SwingWorker` if you need to perform background tasks. If there are no background tasks, I would just use a `javax.swing.Timer` something like this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(duration, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        setVisible(false);
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

instead of

```
try 
{ 
    Thread.sleep(duration); 
} catch (Exception e) {}

setVisible(false);
```

Notice how I call the `showSlashAndExit` inside the timer also, instead in the `main`. Or maybe you don't want that. I'm not really sure about the flow of your program.

**EDit** Test this program. It runs fine. It displays for 5 seconds then exits

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Splash extends JWindow{
    int duration;

    public Splash(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;

        showSplash();
    }

    public void showSplash() {

        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        Timer timer = new Timer(duration, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        timer.start();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                Splash splash = new Splash(5000);
            }   
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So correct me if I do something wrong please. I should paste your answer in constructor, yes? I have made global "private Timer timer;" and made new one Timer in constructor, right?

Comment: I don't want to give you the wrong answer. So please can you elaborate in the flow if your program. Which calls are made in which order and for what reason

Comment: OK 1. I create First splashScreen. 2. Do something in programm. 3. Calling Exit SplashScreen when exiting programm.

Comment: +1, the start splash screen code executes on a regular Thread so Thread.sleep() has no effect on the painting of the GUI. When you exit the app your code is executed from within a listener. All listener code executes on the Event Dispatch Thread, so the Thread.sleep() blocks the EDT and prevents the GUI from repainting. You are lucky that the start splash screen works because all GUI code should be executed on the EDT. See Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: I'm not etirely sure, but I think it should go inside your showSplash method. Just replace the the try catch

Comment: I want to have both SplashScreen for about 5 seconds visible.

Comment: OK. When I am trying to replace that THREAD with Your Timer it says that constructor is not defined for this arguments

Comment: @user2776828 Have you even tried what I suggested yet? replace you try/catch with the timer code I gave you. Also you may not want the `showSplashAndExit();` inside the `actionPerferformed()`

Comment: @user2776828 you need to make sure to import `javax.swing.Timer` and not `java.util.Timer`

Comment: @user2776826 If it showed the screen before, adding the timer will not cause it not to work. Did you accidently delete the `setVisible(true)`?

Comment: OK. I have done what You said. Splash screen appears but disappears really fast.

Comment: @user2776828 I have no idea what you're doing wrong, but when I test it out, it works just fine. See me **Edit** . Test it out, it runs just fine

Comment: Maybe another way: Could you point me where to paste your code? and what to invoke?

Comment: It Works, but not in my case. Peeskillet do you have some chat or email?

Comment: @user2776828 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44061/discussion-between-peeskillet-and-user2776828)

Comment: @user2776828 click on the link